# How to cache third-party packages in client-side so any other application can use it?

Tags: javascript, performance, caching

I have an application which has a lot of third-party dependencies. Now I want to have them cached in a place so that any other application that gets loaded can load the third-party dependencies from that cached place.

I am not sure on the caching part and how to achieve it. Any help will be really appreciated.